# Matching mulitple criteria across 2 sheets and pulling some data from that match in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets of data, one is a list of 4000+ companies and some data about the company (including a CUSIP and an issue date). The other lists stock prices per day for a said list of companies spanning multiple years.

I need to match the CUSIP and the issue date from the first sheet with that of the second and extract a number from sheet 2 where both where a match and put it in sheet one in a colomn next to the other data from that company.

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRPrg.png)
[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEPbw.png)

I tried `=VLOOKUP(E1076&O1076;Sheet1!A:Sheet1!K;11;FALSE)` but all this did was give me a `#NAME` error same for when I tried to do this on the same sheet

I tried  `=INDEX(W:AP,MATCH(1,(X:X=D5)*(AE:AE=N5),0),42)` but that just tells me it isn't a formula to begin with

[Combined Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVhY2.png)

Comment: Have you entered your second formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter? Also, you range for the index should be 1 column only (W:W instead of W:AP) otherwise INDEX doesn't know in which column to pick the result.

Comment: I tried that Pomul, Ctrl-Shift-Enter didn't make a difference.
At what column do I point Index then? The one that gives the value that I need to pull?

Comment: I was just taking a quick shot at it! The Matrix lookup part of this might be helpful: https://www.xelplus.com/excel-index-and-match/ Also, can you include the column letters and row numbers in your screenshots? and also indicate clearly where you need the output.

Comment: I added a Combined Sheets image

I'd need to match the issue date(D Column) and 9-Digit-Cusip (N column) of the left most table (the one without the blue) to the Dates (U column) and the 9-digit-Cusip (AB column) of the right most table. And where it matches I need to pull the Assets Total (AG column) and put it next to the match in the left most table (so let's say the R column).


The table to the left is 4000+ rows and the on the right is now 80000 but will be much longer.

Answer (score 0):

In Column R:

`{=INDEX(AG,MATCH(D2&N2, U&AB,0))}`

will work for you but will likely be slow (make sure to enter with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>)

You can try and mitigate the lag by using defined ranged (e.g. U2:U4000&AB2:AB4000) but since your list is ever growing I'll guess that the lag will come back pretty quick.

To keep things faster, I suggest you use a helper column where you concatenate U and AB. Let's say column AC:
`=U2&AB2`
(copied all the way down)

You can then use a simple `INDEX`/`MATCH`:

`=INDEX(=INDEX(AG,MATCH(D2&N2, AC,0))`

You could also concatenate D and N to another column and use that column as your lookup value.